# Access control to rest services with spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security, spring-boot

I played a bit with spring-boot security. And I use mongodb, spring-boot-starter-data-rest, spring-boot-starter-security and spring-boot-starter-web. I used possibilities that automatic expos repository like REST service. I have two repositories users and customers. Users repository is for accounts. 
After extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/users/**")
    .hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/", "/customers")
    .hasRole("USER")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().permitAll();
}
```

A can not control access to /users/ page  with users where they have ADMIN role. I got authentication when accessing to service but every user wit every roles can access everywhere. What should be configured yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you need to take a look at [Method Security Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#method-security-expressions) features of Spring Security. Especially annotations `@PreAuthorize`/`@PostAuthorize`.

Comment: Yes, and to a method from which class? I have only entity class users.java and customer.java. I use automatic generated REST?

Comment: So you will need to implement controller + service layer explicitly with usage of Spring Data JPA repositories. After that best place for `@PreAuthorize`/`@PostAuthorize` is on service layer methods.

Comment: I can not use MongoDB auto exposure entity(with generated REST), wen I wish implement Access Control?